# Custom Post Type giving a 404 error in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I created a plugin to create a custom post type for a website I'm building. When I click on the permalink I get a 404 error. My code is shown below.

```
//////// Create Rates Custom Post
function rate_groupings_custom_post() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Rate Groups', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Rate Group', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New Group', 'Group' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Group' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Group' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Group' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Groups' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Group' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Groups' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Groups found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Groups found in the Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Rate Groups'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Menu area to add Group',
    'public'        => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'menu_position' => 35,
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'editor' ),
    'has_archive'   => false,
    'show_in_rest' => false
);

register_post_type( 'rates', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rate_groupings_custom_post' );
```

Comment: Try settings =>  permalinks =>  click save changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I build a custom post type, I alway flush the rewrite rules:

In the sidebar menu on the left, go to Settings > Permalinks, then just click save changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well normally when you get an 404 error on your website, it is not something related to your code per say, it is just that the link is leading to the wrong place or your permalink is not configured correctly.

try reviewing your permalink on the settings of your panel and verify if the pathway created is actually correct.

if you have further doubts the wpbeginner can help you: [WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-posts-returning-404-error/)

good luck :)